# Python's equivalent to null-conditional operator introduced in C# 6

Tags: c#, python

Is there an equivalent in Python to C# [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx)?

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = null;
string s = sb?.ToString(); // No error
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safe dereferencing in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4065085/safe-dereferencing-in-python)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

How about:

```
s = sb and sb.ToString()
```

The short circuited Boolean stops if sb is Falsy, else returns the next expression.

Btw, if getting None is important...

```
sb = ""

#we wont proceed to sb.toString, but the OR will return None here...
s = (sb or None) and sb.toString()

print s, type(s)
```

output:

```
None <type 'NoneType'>
```

---

There was some over-eager deletion of comments in the past, which I want to replicate here as a caveat:

commenter :  *Do you really think it is a good idea to do this in Python, a language that prides itself on code readability?*

me :  *No, I don't.  This answers the question - and illustrates some aspects of boolean short-circuiting - but is too "clever" by half.  If you have a reason to use this form, do so, but be aware its intent is not crystal clear at first glance.*

Comment: Upvote for "too clever by half."  Once it gets introduced into the language I'll use it...

Answer (score 19):

There's a proposal under [PEP-505](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0505/), in the meantime there's a library for this:

```
from pymaybe import maybe

print(maybe(None).toString())
```

Answer (score 15):

Well, the simplest solution would be:

```
result = None if obj is None else obj.method()
```

---

But if you want the exact equivalent having the same thread safety as the C#'s Null-conditional operator, it would be:

```
obj = 'hello'
temp = obj
result = None if temp is None else temp.split()
```

The trade off is that the code isn't really pretty; Also an extra name `temp` gets added to the namespace.

Another way is:

```
def getattr_safe(obj, attr):
    return None if obj is None else getattr(obj,attr)

obj = 'hello'
result = getattr_safe(obj,'split')()
```

Here, trade-off is the function calling overhead, but much clearer code, especially if you are using it multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this function with your required behavior. An advantage of this over chaining `and` is that it's easier to write when it comes to long chains. Heads up this doesn't work with object keys, only attributes.

```
def null_conditional(start, *chain):
    current = start
    for c in chain:
        current = getattr(current, c, None)
        if current is None:
            break
    return current
```

Here's some tests I ran so you can see how it works

```
class A(object):
    b = None
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.b = v

class B(object):
    c = None
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.c = v    

a_1 = A(B(2))
a_2 = A(None)
print(null_conditional(a_1, 'b', 'c')) # 2
print(null_conditional(a_1, 'b', 'd')) # None
print(null_conditional(a_2, 'b', 'c')) # None
print(null_conditional(None, 'b')) # None
print(null_conditional(None, None)) # TypeError: attribute name must be string
```