# Pythonic way to make null conditional accesses

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this code

```
NoneType = type(None)

def get_title(ol: BeautifulSoup):
  a = ol.a
  if not isinstance(a,NoneType):
    s = a.string
    if not isinstance(s,NoneType):
      return s.strip()
  return ""
```

I am a C# programmer and, in C#, we would simply `a?.string?.strip() ?? ""`. The Python maintainers don't think this is enough readable for then, so I am struggling with a way to deal with nulls.

I know there is a PEP about this, but half a decade wasn't enough for them to solve this problem. [At this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285881/pythons-equivalent-to-null-conditional-operator-introduced-in-c-sharp-6), it is provided answers, but for me, it is not understandable at a glance. I also found a library, named PyMaybe, but I couldn't import it. Apparently, it's not on the Python standard library.

**What is the Pythonic way to make these accesses?** I am not satisfied with the nested ifs of my code. Firstly, because of the need to create functions instead of inline statements, secondly, because I need a new if for each access.

Comment: `… is None` is totally sufficient to check for `None` values.

Comment: You can create a similar construct with `(a and a.string or '').strip()`