# Python equivalent of object?.method()

Tags: python

```
    basicInfo = {
    "details": basicSoup.select_one('.basics-description  .basics-text').getText(),
    "dose": basicSoup.select_one('.basics-description .basics-dose').getText(),
    "price": basicSoup.select_one('.basics-description .basics-price').getText(),
    "chemistry": basicSoup.select_one('.basics-description .basics-chemistry').getText(),
    "law": basicSoup.select_one('.basics-description .basics-law').getText(),
    "pharmacology": basicSoup.select_one('.basics-description .basics-pharmacology').getText(),
    "production": basicSoup.select_one('.basics-description .basics-production').getText(),
    "history": basicSoup.select_one('.basics-description .basics-history').getText(),
    "terminology": basicSoup.select_one('.basics-description .basics-terminology').getText(),
    "effects": {
      "text": basicSoup.select_one('.basics-effects .basics-text').getText(),
      "onset": basicSoup.select_one('.basics-effects .basics-onset').getText(),
      "duration": basicSoup.select_one('.basics-effects .basics-duration').getText(),
      "visuals": basicSoup.select_one('.basics-effects .basics-visuals').getText(),
      "crash": basicSoup.select_one('.basics-effects .basics-crash').getText(),
      "hangover": basicSoup.select_one('.basics-effects .basics-hangover').getText(),
    },
    "problems": {
      "text": basicSoup.select_one(".basics-problems > .basics-text").getText(),
    }
  }
```

I'm trying to figure out what the equivalent of JavaScript's `object?.method()` is in Python because some pages don't have the information that other pages do so when BeautifulSoup goes to look for them it throws an error.

```
  File "./chemicalScrape.py", line 48, in <module>
    "crash": basicSoup.select_one('.basics-effects .basics-crash').getText(),
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getText'
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52872515/8627992

Comment: @Talon That's a step in the right direction, but now I'm getting an error: Object of type Something is not JSON serializable

Comment: I would suggest to update your question and add your code snippet. From the error message it is visible that `basicSoup.select_one('.basics-effects .basics-crash')` may return `None` value. You could check for the result of that instruction before calling `.getText()`. For your new issue, I guess we need more information.

Comment: This is a good example of why functions should usually return the same type or raise an error. Multiple return signatures can be a big pain. There are always exemptions of course..

Comment: @JulianSanchez to get the value from the `Something`/`Nothing`-objects, use the `.get()` method, or the `.or_else()`-method if it could contain `None`

Answer (score 1):

This is verbose compared to `object?` but you can use `getattr()` where the third parameter indicates the default value to be returned if the attribute doesn't exist. Since you're about to call it, this should be a function that does nothing. Here you have it written as a lambda:

```
getattr(obj, "method", lambda: None)()
```

Break that out into a separate function and generalize it a bit, and you have:

```
def trycall(obj, method, *args, default=lambda *a, **kw: None, **kwargs):
    return getattr(obj, method, default)(*args, **kwargs)
```

Using your example:

```
# basicSoup.select_one('.basics-effects .basics-crash').getText()
trycall(basicSoup.select_one(('.basics-effects .basics-crash'), "getText")
```